# Is it possible to have a function differentiable but not continuous in a given interval?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Is there any possible function that is not continuous but differentiable in a given interval. It sounds non-logical to me since differentiation is a special limit function in itself therefore non-continuous should be meaning non-differentiable either. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

No: A function which is differentiable at $x$ is continuous at $x$. To prove this, note that the quantity

$$\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right|$$

is a bounded function of $y$ in a deleted neighborhood containing $x$; if $M$ is a bound, then rearranging shows that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x - y|$$

for all $y$ in the deleted neighborhood (and in fact, in the neighborhood).

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. However, you can have a function that is continuous but not differentiable ([Weierstrass Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)).

Comment: Then how can a function be cont. but non-differentiable. Can you give some more detail

Comment: There are infinitely many functions that are continuous but non differentiable. The Weierstrass function is a specific example of such, and  could be described as one of the first fractals studied in mathematical discipline. As for your request for more detail, I would advise that you look into this video: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1/cs1-derivatives-definition-and-basic-rules/cs1-differentiability/v/differentiability?modal=1

Comment: Weierstrass function is well known, but let me ask if anybody know function differentiable in only one point of interval and not differentiable in all other points except this one?

Comment: @zkutch take f(x)=$x^2D(x)$, where $D(x)$ is the Dirichlet function.

Comment: Thanks, @tcb93.